# Azure service bus statistics/Monitoring

Tags: azure, queue, servicebus

I want to make a dashboard which shows the status of our Azure services bus queues and displays the history for "messages added to queue", "length of queue" and "messages processed" etc.  Using the Azure Management Portal, I can see that most of these statistics manually for each queue.

Is there any way to get access to the data that is displayed in the Management Portal through one of the APIs as I want to combine the data from number of queues that we use into a single interface.  I have searched in vain but I don't want to log my own statistics as that seems like redoing a task that Microsoft already perform.

Currently with REST API all I can see is how to get the current approximate count of messages in the queue.

Comment: Did you ever write this? If so, is it in GitHub?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/GlobalX/SbManager

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for this now (wasn't back when the OP created the thread):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/azure/dn163589.aspx (REST)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt348562.aspx (.NET)

Also, I believe it should be available via Azure Insights API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.insights.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fetch the Count of Messages in a Queue, Incoming Messages, Outgoing Messages with the help of the latest [Azure Monitor Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics?redirectedfrom=MSDN#microsoftservicebusnamespaces), with which you can build you own Dashboard. Or you can make use of the [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-azure-monitor) in Azure portal, which allows you to configure dashboards and alerts.